# Как отобразить посты по дате их добавления (от новым к старым)? (python, flask)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Всем привет. Я создаю свой первый сайт с блогами на python и flask. Хочу чтобы все посты отображались по дате их публикации от новым к старым. А они у меня отображаются наоборот, от старым к новым.

код функции для отображения постов

```
@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
    posts = Posts.query.order_by(Posts.date_posted)
    return render_template('posts.html', posts=posts)
```

код базы данных взаимодействующий со всеми постами

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    # author = db.Column(db.String(255))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, 
    default=datetime.utcnow)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255)) 
    # ключ связующий Юзеров с Постами :)
    poster_id = db.Column(db.Integer, 
    db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

а это html код показывающий посты

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class="alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<h1>Blog Posts...</h1>
<br/>

{% for post in posts %}
<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    By: {{ post.poster.username }}<br/>
    {{ post.date_posted }}<br/>
    {{ post.content|safe }}<br/><br/>
    <a href="{{ url_for('post', id=post.id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">View Post</a>

    {% if post.poster_id == current_user.id %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('edit_post', id=post.id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm">Edit Post</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('delete_post', id=post.id) }}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete Post</a>    
    {% endif %}
    <br/><br/>    
</div>
<br/>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Так, ну вроде как, все необходимые снипеты предоставил.
Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

@app.route('/posts')
def posts():
    posts = Posts.query.order_by(desc(Posts.date_posted))
    return render_template('posts.html', posts=posts)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.

Comment: Если вам помогло, отметьте как ответ)